# Encoded string with percent signs in it

Tags: python, string, encoding

In my scraping project I encountered a data point containing a string in the following form

```
string = "d%61b%69a%5f%62%65%79@yaho%6f.fr"
target_string = dabia_bey@yahoo.fr
```

What encoding change should I do to wrongly encoded strings? How can I scrape these broken strings correctly?

Thank you

Comment: No sure what you are asking...could you give an example output? What are you looking to do?

Comment: I am looking for someone to identify the correct encoding or encyription.

Comment: What is the "*correct encoding*" do you want to remove the "%" chars from the string? is this an encrypted message?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote - `unquote(string)`

Comment: The term you're looking for is "url encoding": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Thank you Iain and Brian. It solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need urllib unquote

```py
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> unquote("d%61b%69a%5f%62%65%79@yaho%6f.fr")
'dabia_bey@yahoo.fr'
```